# Can a derived class redefine virtual function with a function of different signature?

Tags: c++, microsoft-documentation

There is somewhat odd sample given in [one of the Microsoft documentation pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/class-cpp?view=vs-2019#example) , which consists of two classes, one is a base class and another one is a derived. The base class has the following virtual function member:

```
virtual void setEars(string type)      // virtual function
{
    _earType = type;
}
```

And another, defined in the derived class, which, as stated in comments, redefines the virtual function:

```
// virtual function redefined
void setEars(string length, string type)
{
    _earLength = length;
    _earType = type;
}
```

These two have different signatures and I haven't ever heard if you actually can redefine a virtual function with a function of a different signature. I compiled this sample and could not find any overriding behavior between these two. Is the sample just misleading or I'm missing something?

Comment: Redefine is not the same as override.

Comment: That's juste one of the many broken examples on MSDN. I don't even bother looking at them anymore.

Comment: @Evg could elaborate a little further without telling me that Microsoft means overloading here, because they clearly don't - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/virtual-functions?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Evg `_earType` is duplicated in both classes, and the comment advertises that the example "Exhibits polymorphism/virtual functions", which it doesn't. There's also a rogue `#define TRUE = 1` which makes no sense and isn't even used.

Comment: @Quentin, found complete example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/class-cpp?view=vs-2019. Yes, this example looks misleading. Agree.

Comment: Microsoft's C++ documentation is really, really bad sometimes. Like "I don't know C++ but my manager told me to write this so we meet this month's quota" bad.

Comment: But at least the comment above, "virtual function redefined", is correct. It is redefined, not overridden. The `setEars` from the base class will be hidden by that redefinition.

Comment: @Evg it's still not correct, since that new function that hides the other one is *not* virtual ;)

Comment: @Quentin, **virtual function** in the base class **redefined** with a non-virtual one.

Comment: @Evg I do have to admire your determination to salvage this trainwreck of an example :D

Comment: @Quentin, I'm just trying to squeeze at least a little bit of sense out of it. :)

Comment: Nowadays MS have their Visual Studio documentation on [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs) so it's pretty easy to propose changes. I think I got the last `#include <iostream.h>` out of the documentation that way :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the sample just misleading or I'm missing something?

This example is indeed misleading.
When overriding a virtual function in a derived type, it must come with the same signature as it is defined in the base class. If that is not the case, the function in the child class will be considered as its own entity and is not considered in a polymorphic function call. Additionally, it will hide the name of the base classes function, which is considered bad practice, as it violates the "is-a" relationship in public inheritance.

In order to prevent such accidental hiding, C++ introduced the `override` keyword. When overriding a virtual function, it then must have a matching signature, otherwise, the compiler will reject it.

Comment: Another motivating reason for the ```override``` proposal was when a base class signature changed, and previously overriding functions suddenly stopped overriding it, silently switching into an introduction of a new (possibly non-virtual) function.  Using ```override``` makes catching those situations trivial.